# How to fix Truncated incorrect datetime value: 'Apr 25, 2017 11:48:45 AM' error during insert?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

My dates are in the format: `Apr 25, 2017 11:48:45 AM` and I have converted them into datetime format using `STR_TO_DATE('Apr 25, 2017 11:48:45 AM', '%b %d, %Y %h:%i:%s')`. Now following is the shape of my table contains `time` as formatted date:

[image]

I want to insert this table into another table as:

**TABLE:**

```
CREATE TABLE `locations` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  KEY `locations_uid_IDX` (`uid`,`time`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `locations_time_IDX` (`time`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**INSERTION:**

```
INSERT INTO Transformation_Tables.locations

SELECT 
    uid, 
    latitude, 
    longitude, 
    STR_TO_DATE(time, '%b %d, %Y %h:%i:%s') as time,
    STR_TO_DATE(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as created_at
from creditfix.locations;
```

During insertion I am facing this error :

```
SQL Error [1292] [22001]: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect datetime value: 'Apr 25, 2017 11:48:45 AM'
  com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect datetime value: 'Apr 25, 2017 11:48:45 AM' . Please help me out.
```

Comment: dont use the 12h format... use the 24h format when you insert

Comment: I think the converted dates are already in twenty four hours format after conversion. As shown in the table column `time` @maSTAShuFu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ISSUE

```
 STR_TO_DATE(time, '%b %d, %Y %h:%i:%s') as time
```

solution

`STR_TO_DATE('May 12, 2017 3:05:19 PM', '%b %d, %Y %l:%i:%s %p') as time`

'2017-05-12 15:05:19'

Comment: do you know how would I convert `May 12, 2017 3:05:19 PM` into 24 hour format date?  STR_TO_DATE(`'May 12, 2017 3:05:19 PM'`, '%b %d, %Y %h:%i:%s') gives me '2017-05-12 03:05:19'.

Comment: Shoud be H for 24H

Comment: Not working !! `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('May 12, 2017 3:05:19 PM', '%b %d, %Y %H:%i:%s') as time` gives me ''2017-05-12 03:05:19''

Comment: Yup i got the format :) its `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('May 12, 2017 3:05:19 PM', '%b %d, %Y %l:%i:%s %p') as time` giving me = `'2017-05-12 15:05:19'`

Comment: Thanks !! Please update the answer completely :) with this format