# There seems to be an error with mySQL database that i can't fix. ERROR Code 1292:

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, where-clause, sql-delete

i get an error when putting in the code

```
delete from littering_event_alarm where Event < date_sub(now(), interval 30 DAY);
```

This is the full error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect datetime value: '21/07/2020 16:05:35'

any help is appreciated

Comment: Is `Event` a date? Its not the most likely name for a date

Comment: @RiggsFolly Event is the column name that contains the date the alarm was triggered in our system

Comment: @jlfish1997 , can you check the DATATYPE of EVENT column. Looks like you are comparing two different types. What datatype is Event ? Check that first. Probably a string and not datetime

Comment: Is `Event` a DateTime column or a string?

Comment: `21/07/2020 16:05:35 is incorrect, in MySQL it should be `2020-07-01 16:05:35` to be considered a datetime value

Comment: @theDbGuy ive just checked and ive set it as a VarCHAR, do i need to set it as a datetime ?

Comment: Looks same as following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44300624/how-to-fix-truncated-incorrect-datetime-value-apr-25-2017-114845-am-error

Comment: just go with GMB's answer below. That is what you need @jlfish1997

Comment: Don't store dates in `VARCHAR`. This is a design flaw. -1

Comment: @theDbGuy thank you for the help

Comment: @TheImpaler fixed it now, pretty new to sql / mySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that `event` is of a string datatype, not of a `date`-like datatype (`datetime`, `timestamp`).

Using the wrong datatype is the root of many evils (eg: it puts at risk the integritu of your data and hurts efficiency), and I would highly recommend fixing your data model and store dates as dates.

In the meantime: if `event` consistently uses format `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss`, then you can use `str_to_date()` to turn it to a `datetime`:

```
delete from littering_event_alarm  
where str_to_date(event, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s') > now() - interval 30 day
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: Whilst this answer is correct for your current situation, I can't emphasise the 2nd paragraph enough.  Store your data in the correct format !!!!

Comment: i'll take notice of it, pretty new to sql/ MySQL so still learning how to do it.
thank you for the advice